# contact form 7 did not send an email

Tags: wordpress

I have used contact form 7 for one of my wordpress sites. I have also integrated it  and when I try to send the test message from the site to my email it did not sent the message but it give me successfully message

```html
<label> الاسم
    [text text-446] </label>

<label> تاريخ الميلاد 
    [date date-372] </label>

<label> البريد الاكتروني 
    [email email-990] </label>

<label>رقم التليفون 
    [tel tel-20] </label>

</label>

<label> أختار البلد 
    [text* text-284]</label>

<label> الموضوع
    [text text-446] </label>

<label>البرنامج الذي ترغب بحجزه 
    [select your the tours "برامج علاجيه " "برنامج change your life" "برنامج لعلاج فيرس  سي"]</label>

<label> الموعد المقترح للقيام بالرحلة 
    [date date-185] </label>

<label> ملاحظات
    [textarea textarea-655] </label>

<label>الفحوصات المطلوبه
    [file file-218]</label>

[submit "أرسال"]
```

[my ingeration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nntqt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check your email is correct or not, To ensure that You need to do this as the image shown. 
[image]